# create a email checker using php codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email-validation

Please help me in creating a form which allows a user to submit valid email.

When someone try to enter an email id, it should be validated before submitted to data base. Some of the  examples for junk email ids are `test@abc.com`, `123@xyz.com` etc.

If an user try to enter an email id as mentioned in the above example, it should be verified whether it is a valid email id or not and also check if the user with the email id already exists?

Kindly help me building a code in php codeigniter.

Comment: You mean valid syntax, or a valid, working e-mail that belongs to someone? The former is achievable via CodeIgniter's Form Validator class - look it up, it can validate e-mails. The latter is not possible.

Comment: show us your effort if you wont your code how we are gona know that  you are trying some thing

Comment: have you got some idea from my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a build-in functionality in CI handling this for you. It is in the form validation library.

See: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

note the valid_email rule which is already provided for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, and for checking if the email actually exists in the database you could use a callback method. 

See: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: Hi,

Actually what i want is valid working e-mail! Is it possible through a third party api?

Please clarify, thank you.

Comment: If you want a valid working e-mail (an existing e-mail) you will need your user to confirm his e-mail before you are storing it in the database. I don't think there is a third party solution for this, as it would require the third party provider to keep track of every existing e-mail (which is improbable).

So perhaps send a confirmation e-mail with a link to your controller (urdomain.com/contr/meth) with a method that on confirmation puts the email in the database/activates the user or what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also validate the email domain using dns.

```
public function check_domain($email)
{
    if( ! (bool) checkdnsrr(preg_replace('/^[^@]++@/', '', $email), 'MX'))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would like to give you a function for checking email address domains either they exists or not and after that i will try to figure out verification process that either user has already been registered from before or not and reference link to [checkdnsrr()](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php).

**I have divided my answer into three parts**

1. **Verifying the Domain either it do exist or not**
2. **Client side verification can be done via jquery or html5**
3. **Unique Email address to be registered**

---

> Part 1

---

Try this function with several different domain names. This code work for me and i hope wi

```
function validate_email($email="zazikhan1@wowowowowowowowoowoowowowo.com"){

   $exp = "^[a-z\'0-9]+([._-][a-z\'0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([._-][a-z0-9]+))+$";

   if(stristr($exp,$email)){

      if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),"MX")){
        echo 'good to go';
      }else{
        echo 'domain cant be verified';
      }

   }else{

  echo 'sorry regular expression does not match';

   }    
}
```

---

> Part 2

---

If you want to do that by jquery so visit [jquery rain](http://www.jqueryrain.com/) and select the plugin what ever you like but if you like to that in html5 just simply

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
```

In html5 email will automatically validate either user have put the email by seeing `@` sign in it .

And `required` tag will simply see either user have full fill the email field before proceeding further.

---

> Part 3

---

Here is the code for to don't register those email which have registered already.

```
 function subscriber()
   {
       $subscriber=$this->input->post('subscriber');
       $query=$this->cartmodel->get_record('subscriber',array('email'=>$subscriber));
       if($query)
       {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '<script type="text/javascript">alert("you are already registered with us")</script>'); 
          redirect('views');
       }
       else
       {
        $data=array('email'=>$this->input->post('subscriber'));
        $this->cartmodel->insert_data('subscriber',$data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '<script type="text/javascript">alert("you have sucessfully subscribed with us")</script>');
        redirect('views');
       }
   }
```